# How to replace substrings in the Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

good afternoon.
I have a bat code that checks if my html file has a character and modifies it, but the code does not work if my html has a name that contains space, can you please help me solve this problem?
It has to be in bat and there is no way to work only with names without space, because they vary according to the users, it follows the code that I have and that works only with names that do not contain space.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
SET "OLD=""
SET "NEW="
SET "FILE=C:\Users\DI\Desktop\teste teste.html"
SET "NFILE=C:\Users\DI\Desktop\txt.txt"
dl %NFILE% /q
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %FILE%|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%OLD%=%NEW%%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X >> "%NFILE%"
    ) ELSE echo.
)
copy "%NFILE%" "%FILE%"
pause
del "%NFILE%"
```

Comment: Simple: `type "%FILE%"`  But you are also missing a caret before the pipe.

Comment: @Squashman: escaping is not neccessary (and produces an error), as the whole command string is enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Can you help me solve this error, please? I can not solve it at all.

Comment: What didn't you understand about my first comment. You need to put quotes around your file variable.  Any time you have spaces in file names or paths your put quotes around it. `'type "%FILE%" ^|find /n /v ""'`

Comment: So the code you are using is straight from DosTips.com.  Why didn't you just ask the question on their forum?  That is an older version of the script.  The newer version was created in 2010, so you are using a very old old version.  http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1516

Comment: Squashman, I did not use the most current code because I could not figure out where to put the file path and change the characters.

Comment: @userTi, the syntax for the strings to replace and the file name to process did not change from the old version to the new version.  If you need to tag someone in a comment you use the @ symbol before their name.  If you do not use the @ symbol, the user does not get notified of your response to them.  And as I said in my first post, DosTips is a fully functional forum to ask questions on.  The code came from there so why not ask the question there.  I gave you the link to the topic.